# I/O dispatch worker terminated abnormally

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, rest-client

In our production environment, we are encountering an issue while fetching records based on an index. Despite verifying the JVM, we're experiencing an exception 'Request cannot be executed i/o reactor status stopped' during high concurrency. We've noticed occasional connection closures leading to various errors, even though there are no prior logged errors. Notably, we never manually call 'client.close()'.

We use a single client, and every few weeks, it sporadically disconnects, causing our application to continuously fail with the mentioned exception until we recreate the client. This problem persists across multiple customers/installations and seems unexpected, especially with the 7.10 version of the client

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request cannot be executed; I/O reactor status: STOPPED`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.